# Populating a listBox with sql query results

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Am trying to populate a listbox with values generated by a query, the code runs without any problems but the listbox is not displaying any results, what am i doing wrong, is there anything missing??

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM products where code = "+textBox1.Text;
                SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn); //c.con is the connection string
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                            if (reader.Read())
                            {
                                listBox1.Items.Add(reader["description"].ToString() + ":    "+reader["price"].ToString());
                                listBox1.Refresh();
                            }
                        reader.Close();
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your code column is of string type then

```
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM products where code = '"+textBox1.Text + "'";
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn); //c.con is the connection string
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
    {
          conn.Open();
          using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
          {
                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(reader["description"].ToString() + ":    "+reader["price"].ToString());
                }
                reader.Close();                   
           }
           conn.Close();
     }
```

Also to add all values, use while instead of if to traverse all the records in the reader. And also close the connection after the using statement. 
I am sure the wrong sequence is causing the issue.

Comment: am Still new brah...my rep is 7 so i cant yet  but as soon as i reach 15 ill

Comment: Sure. Will wait for it

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some assumptions here about your code, is 'code' a number? If not, did you try:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM products where code = '"+textBox1.Text+"'";
```

?

Comment: Is your code even reaching:
    
    listBox1.Items.Add

Comment: Yes 'code' is a database column name and am not sure if it reaches that point'

Comment: its type is bigint, and no the code does not reach listbox1.items.add()

Comment: Do some more testing, try this: String sql = "SELECT * FROM products"; in other word, remove the where clause.